# Dynamic component and conditional rendering in Vue 2

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Recently I've played with dynamic components with Vue 2.

Let's say we have two components SignIn and SignOut that must be conditionally rendered.

```
import SignIn from '~/components/SignIn.vue
import SignUp from '~/components/SignUp.vue

export default {
components: {
  SignOut,
  SignIn
}
data() {
  return { 
    condition: true
  }
}
```

I usually use the Vue conditional render pattern as follow:

```
<template>
  <SignIn v-if="condition" />
  <SignUp v-else />
</template>
```

But I can achive the same result with dynamic components pattern.

```
<script>
data() {
  return {
    condition: true,
    component: this.condition ? 'SignIn' : 'SignUp'
  }
}
</script>

<template>
  <component :is="component" />
</template>
```

What do you think about it?

Comment: If switching between several components, dynamic is less template code.  But for two, `v-if` is easier to understand the purpose at a glance.

Answer (score 0):

#### Conditional Rendering (v-if) :

Conditional rendering through v-if is good choice in that situation as it has very limited options like two components which can be call faster than dynamic component pattern.

For more details: https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/conditional.html

#### Dynamic Component Pattern:

This can be useful in the case where components are more as it looks cleaner and not bound to limited options.

For more details: https://blog.logrocket.com/making-components-dynamic-vue-3#dynamic-components-syntax

In your scenario `conditional render pattern` would be the nice choice.